# Transit information UK - AMS - Buenos Aires

Tags: schengen, transit, ams

I am wondering whether 1 hour is sufficient transit time at Amsterdam Schipol for the following flights:

Newcastle, UK - Amsterdam - Buenos Aires.

I have read that Schipol is an efficient and fairly small airport, but still, one hour isn't a lot of time. As the UK is non-Schengen, will I have to go through passport control and customs again at Amsterdam before going to the gate for my Buenos Aires flight?

The ticket was bought as one ticket, and both flights are with KLM.

Comment: If the ticket was sold as one ticket, that means KLM thinks there is enough time and will get you to your destination if for some reason there isn't.

Comment: @DJClayworth thanks for your reply. The ticket was booked by a travel agent. Does this change your view? I know I will be put up in a hotel etc if I miss the flight, but my point is, what's the point of booking these flights if there's a high probability of missing the flight? Has the travel agent mislead me simply to get a sale?

Comment: As long as KLM sold the trip as a single ticket my comment does not change. If your agent bought the tickets separately that's different.

Comment: @DJClayworth they bought it as one ticket. Thanks for your help